How to convert digital value got using I2S from ICS 43434 MEMS mic to dB
I'm working on an ESP32 project where I use the ICS-43434 MEMS microphone and I2S for recording audio. I'm trying to calculate the sound pressure level (SPL) in dB SPL, but the values I'm getting seem incorrect. The room has a noise level of approximately 40 dB, but my calculated values are consistently around 65 dB.
Microphone and setup:
Microphone: ICS-43434 (with -26 dB FS at 94 dB SPL)
Microcontroller: ESP32
Software: ESP-IDF
Problem: I'm using the following code to read from I2S, calculate RMS, and convert it to dB SPL. However, the calculated values are too high for a quiet room, and I'm unsure if I need further adjustments in how I'm handling the microphone data.
My Current approach (pseudocode):
Sound pressure level (SPL) constants
#define MAX_SAMPLE_VALUE        8388607.0f (Maximum value for a 24-bit sample (2^23))
#define MICROPHONE_SENSITIVITY_DB -26.0     
#define L_94                    94.0            
#define BUFFER_SIZE             1024            
#define NB                      (CONFIG_SAMPLE_RATE / BUFFER_SIZE) 


Initialize the I2S driver and microphone.
Continuously read I2S data into a buffer.
For each buffer
Extract raw 24-bit audio samples: int32_t raw_sample = i2s_readraw_buff[i];
Normalize the samples to a range between -1 and 1:
float normalized_sample = (float)(raw_sample) / MAX_SAMPLE_VALUE;
Calculate the RMS value from the samples:
float rms = sqrt(sum_of_squares / samples_read);
if (rms < 1e-9) rms = 1e-9;
Convert the RMS to dB SPL using the formula:
Lz = 20 * log10(RMS) - MICROPHONE_SENSITIVITY_DB + L_94
Accumulate dB SPL values.
After recording, calculate the average SPL (LZeq).

Questions:

Am I using the correct formula for converting RMS to dB SPL based on microphone sensitivity?
Should I remove the normalization of samples?
Is there a better way to handle the raw I2S data for more accurate SPL results?
Any suggestions for improving the calculation or adjusting the approach for more accurate SPL readings would be appreciated

I read about other topics on the exchange but none seem to help me.

Overall that looks reasonable. There are a few things to consider here.

You don't apply any frequency weighting or proper time constant. SPL meters have different frequency weighting curves (A, C, Z, etc) and time constants (fast, slow). I'm guessing your main problem is frequency weighting. Your room is reading probably at 40 dBSPL(A)/slow. Unweighted SPL tend to be a lot higher because of low frequency noise (traffic, HVAC, fridge, compressors, etc).
40dBSPL is at the low end of what your microphone can do. It tops at at 120 dBSPL and has an SNR of 65 dB, that means your noise floor sits at 35 dBSPL. Getting a good reading at those levels would be difficult. I would not use this microphone for anything under 50 dBSPL.
Calculating the average SPL needs to be done by averaging in Energy, not in dB.


Am I using the correct formula for converting RMS to dB SPL based on microphone sensitivity?

Yes.

Should I remove the normalization of samples?

There are various ways of doing this. Yours is not wrong, but I prefer to directly convert samples into Pascals (Pa), so I don't have to worry about calibration later. In your case you have $0 dBFS = 120 dBSPL = 20 Pa$ so I would normalize
$$ x_{Pascal} = \frac{x_{int}}{2^{23}}\cdot 20\mu \text{Pa} \cdot 10^{120/20}  $$
or in other words: normalize to $\pm 20$.

Thank you, I implemented your converting samples to Pascals logic and I am getting the a similar 65dB result with it as well.
// Normalize to ±20 Pascals (using 120 dB SPL=20 Pa)
float x_Pascal =(float)raw_sample /(float)(1<< 23)*20.0f;
// Convert RMS in Pascals to dBSPL
float Lz=20.0*log10(rms/(20e-6));
I searched a bit on Google about what should general room noise level's be and itsays somewhat between 60 to 70 at multiple pages. I think my reference of 40dB itself was flawed.
I would read a bit more about frequency weighting curves (A,C,Z,etc) and time constants (fast,slow)

Full spec for SPL meters is IEC 61672 parts 1 to 3 (part is at https://webstore.iec.ch/en/publication/5708). How deep you need to dive into this depends on the scope of your projects: is it a hobby thing, a commercial app or something that needs to hold up in court.
